# match regex to array of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

in page I am making I need to have a string ring buffer with a specific size. I use an array for this purpose and just push and unshift. a single index is a single character. I don't want to use a string since then each time I push a character into buffer a copy occurs. Now I need to use a regex on this buffer. The problem with that is that now everytime I want to match I need to `array.join()` it is rather costly to do that...

Now I am wondering if it would be possible to directly use the regex on the array of characters instead of first converting it into a string.

I suppose if there were a mutable string type I would never have this problem...

Comment: I guess you could implement your own regex engine in JS, but probably would be slower than joining the array.

Comment: Why does a copy being made matter?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol because I need 100000 operations per second. Copying 524288 characters each time is not feasible.

Comment: So you think push/unshift don't have to copy the array?

Comment: @melpomene well I don't know for sure if it does under the hood but no it doesn't seem to as the array length is modified and the shifted elements still exists at after the shift. If you know more than I do please enlighten me

Comment: I would recommend first implement the `array.join()` and benchmark it, it might be good enough for your requirements

Comment: Just out of curiosity can you show us the regexp?

Comment: @torazaburo not a single rexexp, could be anything the user has put in. Just like sublime text regex search option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed..! The JS strings are immutable however your concerns on their concatenation to be time consuming are not very justifiable. I can confirm that both in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE11 and Safari an `Array.prototype.join()` operation over an array of 1,000,000 random characters take around 10~40ms depending on the engine. Yes... that's how it is. (especially Spider Monkey shines) Let's see

```
var   arr = [],
    match = [],
  longStr = "",
    count = 1000000,
    start = 0,
      end = 0;

for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
  arr.push((+new Date()*Math.random()).toString(36)[0]);
}
start = performance.now();
longStr = arr.join("");
end = performance.now();
console.log("Concatenation took "+(end-start)+" msecs");
// Concatenation took 10.875 msecs.. Wow Firefox..!
start = performance.now();
match = longStr.match(/7{5,}/g);
!match && (match = [])
end = performance.now();
console.log("Regex match took "+(end-start)+" msecs and found " +match.length+" matches as: ", match);
//Regex match took 6.550000000046566 msecs and found 1 matches as: ["77777"]
```

So after having performed these tests, i have decided to give a try to answer your question. We need to invent our own mutable string object. Actually creating it is quite simple. An exotic array object with special functionality which also has access to `Array.prototype` functions. Just like a string object it will have an extra property called `primitiveValue` and every time the length property is updated we will perform a `this.primitiveValue = this.join();` operation so that all `Array.prototype` functions accessing to the `length` property will automatically update the `primitiveValue`. This will slow down the performance if we have a write heavy workflow. The good thing is we have the full control on how we update the `primitiveValue`. If we like, we can skip updating it at every write access to the length property and can do it manually before we apply regex to the string content. Or we can even add regex functions to the `RingBuffer.prototype` and monkey patch concatenating the `primitiveValue` job to them. Many possibilities here.

```
function RingBuffer(){
    this.primitiveValue = "";
    this.__len;
    Object.defineProperty(this, "length", {
                                             enumerable: true,
                                           configurable: true,
                                                    get: this.getLength,
                                                    set: this.setLength
                                          });
}
RingBuffer.prototype = Array.prototype;
RingBuffer.prototype.constructor = RingBuffer;
RingBuffer.prototype.getLength = function(){
                                   return this.__len;
                                 };
RingBuffer.prototype.setLength = function(val){
                                   this.__len = val;
                                   this.primitiveValue = this.join("");
                                 };
var ringu = new RingBuffer();
```

So i filled up `ringu` with 100,000 random characters. The benchmarking on Chrome 49 is like this;

```
var longStr = "",
      count = 100000,
      start = performance.now(),
        end = 0;
for (var i=1; i<=count; i++){
  ringu.push((+new Date()*Math.random()).toString(36)[0]);
  if (!(i % 10000)){
    end = performance.now();
    console.log(i/10000+". 10000 pushes done at :"+(end - start)+" msecs");
    start = end;
  }
}
console.log("ringu is filled with " + count + " random characters");
start = performance.now();
longStr = ringu.join("");
end = performance.now();
console.log("Last concatenation took "+(end-start)+" msecs");

1. 10000 pushes done at :1680.6399999996647 msecs
2. 10000 pushes done at :4873.2599999997765 msecs
3. 10000 pushes done at :8044.155000000261 msecs
4. 10000 pushes done at :11585.525000000373 msecs
5. 10000 pushes done at :14642.490000000224 msecs
6. 10000 pushes done at :17998.389999999665 msecs
7. 10000 pushes done at :20814.979999999516 msecs
8. 10000 pushes done at :24024.445000000298 msecs
9. 10000 pushes done at :27146.375 msecs
10. 10000 pushes done at :30347.794999999925 msecs
ringu is filled with 100000 random characters
Last concatenation took 3.510000000707805 msecs
```

So depending on how often you make writes or how often you need concatenation of the `primitiveValue` before applying regex you can decide on where to invoke the `this.join("");` instruction. An average concatenation time for 500K item RingBuffer would be less than 30ms.

Well... and this is the SpiderMonkey results. So if you are to run similar code on Node.Js may be it's wiser to try [JXCore](https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore) configured with Spider Monkey or ChakraCore engine instead of Node with V8.

```
1. 10000 pushes done at :710.310000000005 msecs
2. 10000 pushes done at :1831.4599999999991 msecs
3. 10000 pushes done at :3018.199999999997 msecs
4. 10000 pushes done at :4113.779999999999 msecs
5. 10000 pushes done at :5144.470000000008 msecs
6. 10000 pushes done at :6588.179999999993 msecs
7. 10000 pushes done at :7860.005000000005 msecs
8. 10000 pushes done at :8727.050000000003 msecs
9. 10000 pushes done at :9795.709999999992 msecs
10. 10000 pushes done at :10866.055000000008 msecs
ringu is filled with 100000 random characters
Last concatenation took 1.0999999999912689 msecs
```